# CDATA Format in XML

Tags: xml

I am using CDATA within my XML file, like so:

```
<markerHTML1><![CDATA[<center><u>Header Goes Here</u></center><br /><li>Example text goes here.</li><br /><li>You can even use <a href="http://www.weather.gov" target="_blank">links</a>.</li>]]></markerHTML1>
```

When everything is on one line like above, it works perfectly. However, I would like to use multiple lines so it is easier to edit (as opposed to scrolling all the way through one long line), like so:

```
<markerHTML1>
   <![CDATA[<center><u>Header Goes Here</u></center><br />
      <li>Example text goes here.</li><br />
      <li>You can even use <a href="http://www.weather.gov"target="_blank">links</a>.</li>]]>
</markerHTML1>
```

The problem is, when it is formatted like it is in the second example, it no longer works. Any idea why this would be the case?

Thanks!

---EDIT---

Here is the PHP code that refers to the tags markerHTML1, markerHTML2, etc.

```
for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){

$lat = $xml->{'markerLat'.$i};
$lon = $xml->{'markerLon'.$i};
$html = $xml->{'markerHTML'.$i};

        if(strlen($lat)>0){

        echo "L.marker(['$lat','$lon']).addTo(map).bindPopup('$html');\n";
        }

        else{
        #Break out of the loop since there are no more markers defined
        $i=100;
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain in what way "it no longer works", XML is simply a data format. So what are you trying to do with the XML that fails, in what way does it fail?

Comment: I will edit the original question to show the PHP code that uses the data within `<markerHTML1>`. It just plots markers on a map. Using it the second way, the map itself no longer even shows up.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this:

```
L.marker(['$lat','$lon']).addTo(map).bindPopup('$html');
```

Is JavaScript code, yes? If you concatenate your `$html` value directly into that, it will equate to something like this:

```
L.marker(['33', '44']).addTo(map).bindPopup('<center><u>Header Goes Here</u></center><br />
  <li>Example text goes here.</li><br />
  <li>You can even use <a href="http://www.weather.gov"target="_blank">links</a>.</li>');
```

Having inlines in the middle of a string literal is invalid JavaScript (unless you precede them with backslashes), so most likely your JavaScript is failing.

Even if you didn't have newlines, this could fail for a variety of reasons (e.g. if your HTML contained a single quote `'`.

Probably the simplest way around this is to encode your HTML as JSON:

```
$htmlJson = json_encode($html);

echo "L.marker(['$lat','$lon']).addTo(map).bindPopup($htmlJson);\n";
```

Note that I have removed the quotes around `$htmlJson` because it should now contain its own quotes.

Comment: Ok, what you are saying makes sense. However, it is PHP code not JS. When I try your suggestions, the map does indeed now show up along with the markers. The only thing that isn't working though is that the markers do not show any popup text once you click on them. Any ideas why that might be? Thanks for your help!